# Single Color Enhancement - MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, colors, computer-vision

I'm writing a RED traffic light detector in matlab and thought that one of the first things to do is to enhance the color red in the input RGB image.

So far this is the code I've used:

```
img_hsv = rgb2hsv(img_rgb);

h_channel = img_hsv(:,:,1);
s_channel = img_hsv(:,:,2);
v_channel = img_hsv(:,:,3);

s_channel = s_channel * 10;

img_hsv_enhanced = cat(3,h_channel,s_channel,v_channel);
img_rgb_enhanced = hsv2rgb(img_hsv_enhanced);
```

Here is a result of the enhancement on an image:

[image]

I have 3 questions:

1. Is the code I've written so far the best way to do this? I.e. I've enhanced the saturation of the image, should I have worked on a different channel?
2. This code results in all 3 colors being enhanced, how can I selectively enhance only the red channel?
3. After converting back to rgb with the function `hsv2rgb` the pixels of my image are not anymore in the range [0,1] or [0,255], but assume a decimal value and sometimes also negative. How can I fix this and bring it back to [0 255]?

Comment: Maybe start reading here: http://www.mathworks.de/discovery/image-enhancement.html . Talking about image enhancement, I would expect something different than oversaturating.

Comment: @Daniel - Thanks for the link, I've already gone through it. I was looking for the advice of an expert on this specific topic, those links are quite general.

Comment: Why are you over-saturating the image? I don't understand the intention of your approach, thus I can only suggest to use one of the described approaches.

Answer (score 2):

1. I think saturation is not the correct approach, at least not initially. As you said, it enhances all colors, and not red specifically. But more importantly, you will probably need to differentiate between red patches corresponding to traffic lights and to other objects (you have some excellent examples in your image - road signs, taillights, pedestrian lights), and saturation might lead to loss of information which could be helpful for this filtering.
2. To enhance the red channel only, you should work in RGB rather than HSV. You can do something like this:

   ```
   r_channel = img_rgb(:,:,1);
   r_channel = uint8(double(r_channel * 2));
   ```

   You should note, however, that this can lead as well to a loss of information in your most important channel, as explained in the previous item.
3. This is caused by the saturation values exceeding 1 when you compute `s_channel = s_channel * 10;`. Try adding `s_channel = s_channel / max(s_channel(:));` after that line. The output image from hsv2rgb should be in the range [0,1]. From there bring it back to [0 255] by rescaling. Be sure to bring the image back to its original datatype as well (most likely uint8): `img_rgb_enhanced = uint8(img_rgb_enhanced * 255);`.